# Android SQLite update query not working?

Tags: android, sqlite

```
public void AddViewCount(String chname)
{
   String selectQuery = "UPDATE  channel_login SET TimesViewed=TimesViewed+1 WHERE channelName="+chname ;
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   System.out.print("Count"+cursor.getCount());  

}
```

I m getting this error message. Can you please point out the culprit?

```
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: Sat1  
(code   1):,while compiling: UPDATE  channel_login SET       
TimesViewed=TimesViewed+1 WHERE channelName=Sat1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
public void AddViewCount(String chname)
{
   String selectQuery = "UPDATE  channel_login SET TimesViewed=TimesViewed+1 WHERE channelName='"+chname+"'";
   SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
   Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
   System.out.print("Count"+cursor.getCount());  

}
```

Adding the ' ' around the text value should work. Also, unless you need the cursor count, you could just use `db.execSQL(selectQuery);` to perform the update.